# Adding add_filter() in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. I have a search functionality in my website. Now I have to apply some custom sql code/filter in the search query coming through $wp_query. I did some googling and saw that add_filter is good option.

The code which I think I can use is given below

```
function apply_custom_filter( $where ) {
global $wp_query;
$where = " AND wp_posts.ID IN (SELECt DISTINCT ID FROm TBL_IDS)";
remove_all_actions ( '__after_loop'); 
return $where;}

add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'apply_custom_filter' );
```

What confuses me is where to use this. Means in which file I have to place this. In my theme's (I have a theme installed) files I have used it inside header.php but not working :(

Can you please help me in showing my the proper file location  to insert it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A similar question was answered on wordpress SE, check the question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80267/where-is-the-best-place-to-use-add-filter - they write there to use functions.php of the plugin. If you don't have a plugin, use functions.php of wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Filters and hooks are generally fired before the page renders. The filter you want to use makes no exceptions.

In this case you should call the filter in your theme's [functions.php file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) or write a simple [must use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

Comment: I have added my code to the top of the functions.php of my theme, but no luck :(
-------------code------------

function posts_where_statement( $where="" ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = " AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,2)";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where_statement' );

Comment: To make the best of WP hooks and filters I'd suggest you to really get how they work and how/when they are fired. [Google is your friend](https://www.google.ie/search?q=wp+filters+hooks).

As far as I can read, your code overrides the SQL statement in **$where** variable and just returns `AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,2)`.

Have you tried using the `.=` operator like: `$where .= " AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,2)"` ?;